# Grid with merged cells, what data structure?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I have a grid with the Dimensions `N x M` with a cell size of `D`.
I have a runtime coordinate `(X,Y)` within that grid.

The grid itself is stored as a one dimensional array of cells. To retrieve the Cell the coordinate `(X,Y)` lies within, I divide the coordinate by `D`:

```cpp
int col = x / dimension; 
int row = y / dimension;
```

to receive the index of a cell, I index it like this:

```cpp
int idx = row * height + col;
```

this works in O(N) with a memory footprint of `N x M`.

So far so good.

What I want to do next is allow merging of cells within that grid.
What I mean by that is something like this:
[image]

In my real world use case, the *cell size* is **usually** a multiple of `D` and I decided that `D` is just the smallest possible cell size.
What I mean by that: The user generates a grid. but the grid has not the smallest possible cell size **initially** for convenience. The cell size a user usually works with is 1024 and the smallest possible cell size is 256. The user initially works with a grid consisting of already merged cells for convenience.
The issue I have is simply the memory footprint. Because 256 is the "granularity" of indexing, I waste a lot of memory if the user works with 1024 cells only.
If I have a grid with 6x8 cells of size 1024, the runtime currently stores 6x8x16 cell datas (6x8 for the user cells and x16 because for every 1024 cell there are 16 cells of size 256)

In my current implementation I **just duplicate cell data when a cell is merged**. That means that my memory footprint is still `N x M`, even though my base cell count is smaller.

What are my possibilities If I want to restrict it to a maximum of `O(log N)` for access and `C` for memory, where `C` is the amount of **real (merged and non-merged) cells**?

I already read upon QuadTrees, but QuadTrees are strictly quadratic and I do not know how someone would handle merged cells beyond quadrant boundaries or even beyond sibling boundaries

(Because this question is more a "what kind of data structure should I use" i was not exactly sure whether SO fits for this question)

Answer (score 1):

I would go with a pair of data structures.  The one is your tree structure which points regions of the graph at cells.  The second is cells, which point back at a list of regions of the graph.

When you merge two cells, you create a merged cell, update all regions pointing at the removed cell to the new one, then attempt to merge regions.  That merge will eliminate things from the tree structure, AND also make the cell data smaller (it now points at fewer regions).  Figuring out which cell at a given point is just a question of finding it within the tree, then finding the cell.

Now what tree should you use?  An obvious choice is a quadtree, which you already know.  But also take a look at a [Hilbert Curve](https://www.compuphase.com/hilbert.htm).  This organizes a rectangle into a single curve that wanders through it, which has a decent chance of putting large chunks of a contiguous region into relatively few stretches of the curve.

Be warned, the overhead of the complex data structure may dwarf the savings that you hope to get.  So try it, but be ready to back out and go with the naïve approach.

Comment: that sounds interesting. I probably forgot to mention that cells are generated at edit-time. They are fixed at runtime (so the tree/data structure needs to be created once and after that it's only accessed)